# Delete one of many DbContexts?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, .net-core

Right now I have two DbContexts which I have been maintaining with the usual Add-Migration and Update-Database. So I have a number of migrations in this ASP.NET Core MVC application. Now I would like to delete one of the contexts. Doing this by just deleting the class that I have created derived from DbContext doesn't work because now all of the migrations in the project reference the DbContext and if it is removed compilation obviously will fail. What is the recommended way to delete a DbContext (by extension delete the database)?

Comment: Isn't this more of an issue with changing the references from context1 to context2? If there is no context, migrations won't be run.

Comment: The problem is resources associated with the DbContext. The migrations have been run so the database has been created. Admittedly in this day and age the resources involved in keeping this database are minimal (mainly disk space). But I want it gone as if it never existed so some time in the future there will not be the question of what this context is that is never used or what is this database that is never used.

Comment: Migrations are only needed to get your from database state A to state N. If all the databases are in state N, you can safely delete the migrations and re-implement them later if needed. If your other context has a reference to all the tables you need you can safely delete it. The POCO classes, annotations (or fluent code) are what define your models. You can also always reverse engineer any existing database to recreate them.

Comment: So you are suggesting delete the database to get it into state N. Then delete all of the migrations manually as well as the DbContext class?

Comment: Kind of. If you remove the database and migrations and you have a context with DbSets and the fluent code and you have not nullified the default initializer [CreateDatabaseIfNotExists](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx), then when you start the app it would create the database with the proper structure.

Answer (score 2):

firstly delete reverse all migrations in DB like this:

`Update-database -context [name Of Context to delete] -migration 0`

then remove all migrations

`Remove-migration -context [name Of Context to delete]`

And now you can feel free to delete the context.

Notice: you lost data some data from DB! (create backup of your data in DB if you need
)